# The best paper from/at/of A

Tags: prepositions

When describing a person who is awarded the best paper, what preposition should be used? It would be great with the explanation why.

- "He is awarded the best paper from conference A?"
- "He is awarded the best paper at conference A?"
- "He is awarded the best paper of conference A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**At** would probably be the most natural sounding. **Of** would work as well, but might be less common. **From** sounds odd, but would be understood.

Also, the present passive doesn't seem like it would be the right tense here. It would more likely be the past passive:

> He was awarded the best paper at conference A

"awarded" is a completed action, but the present passive tends to indicate ongoing, repeated or habitual actions. For example,

> He is awarded the best paper at this conference every year.